# JavaScript, get one object key name knowing the second

Tags: javascript

Let's say I have an object that has two key-values:

```
let object = {name: "abc", id: 12}
```

But let's say, I don't know one of the key-names, so:

```
let object = {<unknown_to_me>: "abc", id: 12}
```

How can I get the first key name if I know the other one? Their positions

THe first one is reachable via:

```
object.id
```

Can I get the other one by positions, the ! operator,...?

Comment: Do you know any part of the property name?

Answer (score 0):

You could do so:

```js
let object = {name: "abc", id: 12};
let knownKeyName = "id";

let objectKeys = Object.keys(object);
let unknownKeyName = objectKeys[objectKeys.length - 1 - objectKeys.indexOf(knownKeyName)];

console.log(unknownKeyName)
```

Comment: What if I don't know their positions? id and name could be like this: let object = {id: 12,name: "abc"}

Comment: But you only have two key-value in the object ?

Comment: Yes... If I switch positions on your example, it logs 12 and I don't want that...I could do it with a if-else, but I wanted to know is there a easier solution

Comment: Okay, I just edited my answer, take a look please.